# How to make the middle of image and links on the same line?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I got this code

```css
#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.linkButton:link,
.linkButton:visited {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 7.5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.linkButton:hover,
.linkButton:active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="logo.png" />
  <a href='index.jsp' class='linkButton'>Home</a>
</div>
```

Somehow the image and the link are not on the same line. Seem that the image is a bit higher than the link.

**How to make the middle of the image & the middle of the link are on the same line (that means I want the middle "-" of "H" on the same line of the middle of the image)?**

You can see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/sersc0tf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.linkButton {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 7.5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  <a href='index.jsp' class='linkButton'>Home</a>
</div>
```

---

Update: In this case only `vertical-align: middle` on `img` will work

```css
.linkButton {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 7.5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
  <a href='index.jsp' class='linkButton'>Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `vertical-align` property. In your case, I think that adding `vertical-align: middle` on both elements should work.